# PHP setcookie() does not work after unsetting $_COOKIE

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I've just written very simple wrapper class for Cookies, which goes as follow:

```
<?php
class Cookie {  

    // expire time of the cookie 31 days
    private static $_expire = '2678400';

    public static function set($name = null, $value = null, $expire = null) {
        if (!empty($name)) {
            $expire = !empty($expire) ? $expire : time() + self::$_expire;
            if (setcookie($name, $value, $expire)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static function get($name = null) {
        if (!empty($name)) {
            return !empty($_COOKIE[$name]) ? $_COOKIE[$name] : false;
        }
        return false;
    }      

    public static function remove($name = null) {
        if (!empty($name)) {
            if (!empty($_COOKIE[$name])) {
                if (setcookie($name, false, time() - self::$_expire)) {
                    unset($_COOKIE[$name]);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
?>
```

However I have a problem when the cookie was initially set, then I want to change the value by first calling :

```
Cookie::remove('session_name');
```

and then

```
Cookie::set('session_name');
```

The second one (set) doesn't set the cookie.

Any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: Also - worth to mention - Cookie::set() returns true - so not quite sure what's wrong. I'm using print_r($_COOKIE) to find out which cookies are set and also send test email after set with all set cookies - and it doesn't create it.

Comment: Well, two things.  You're calling `Session::foo` as opposed to `Cookie::foo` (this may be an oversight, but it's worth trying).  Secondly, `$_COOKIE` is only populated at the next request.  `setcookie` never effects it on the same request.  If you want to track the set cookies, then keep track of each call to `::set`...

Comment: Yes - it's not Session of course (I was typing it) - not quite suer what you mean that $_COOKIE is only populated at the next request - you mean next call to the server - after reload? If so - then it does it - please read comment below.

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstand how cookies work.

The contents of `$_COOKIE` are set *once*, when the HTTP request arrives and before your script starts execution.

If you use `setcookie` to add or modify a cookie, this addition or modification will not be visible until the *next* HTTP request to your server. This is what you are doing in your `Cookie::set` method.

If you are "testing" `Cookie::set` by looking at the contents of `$_COOKIE` (or by using `Cookie::get`, which does the same thing) then you will not see the changes to the cookie *even though they have been made*.

To see what you expect, you should add the value to `$_COOKIE` inside `Cookie::set`. However, I would suggest writing your program in a different manner. You are trying to use cookies like normal variables, which they are not.

Comment: Yes - there is a reload after Cookie::set is called - as I'm using Ajax to set it - and page reloads after successful response using location.reload();

Answer (score 1):

if you whant to change the value of a cookie , there is no need to first remove it , you can call straight `Session::set('session_name');` and the cookie would be overwrited . call `Session::remove('session_name');` only when you don't need the cookie anymore.

Answer (score 0):

if I correctly understood you , you need something like that

```
public static function set($name, $value,$expire) 
{
    setcookie($name, $value, $expire);

   $_COOKIE[$name] = $value;    

}
```

Comment: hmm - sorry - not quite sure - why would I need to assign the value to the cookie index if it's already set using setcookie()?

Comment: depends on your needs, in this example $_COOKIE is  populated at the current request, otherwis - will be populated by next request